# how can I filter an array of objects based on a specific property and return only one property when I insert the parameter into the function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, filter

I can't do this thing. I would like the parameter inserted in the function to return that specific value of the object to me.

If I insert "over" I would like an array with the names whose age is over 50, while on the contrary if I insert under, it doesn't work!

```js
const person = [
  { name: 'Jessica', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ilary', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 70 },
  { name: 'Dan', age: 65 },
  { name: 'Pop', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Maur', age: 68 },
];

let nameOver50 = [];
let nameUnder50 = [];

function check(enter) {
  person.filter(({ name, age }) => {
    if (age > 50 && enter === 'over') {
      nameOver50.push({ name });
    } else if (age < 50 && enter === 'under') {
      nameUnder50.push(name);
    }
  });
  console.log(nameUnder50);
}

check('over');
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: The `filter()` callback function needs to return a boolean that indicates whether the object should be included in the result. And you need to assign the result of `filter()` to somehthing.

Comment: You're only logging `nameUnder50` even if they entered `over`.

Comment: i can't understand, could you help me edit it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you want it to return as an array of `names`, then you should return the `name` only, which is as a string, instead of returning the `name` object.

```js
const person = [
  { name: 'Jessica', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ilary', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 70 },
  { name: 'Dan', age: 65 },
  { name: 'Pop', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Maur', age: 68 },
];

let nameOver50 = [];
let nameUnder50 = [];

function check(enter) {
  enter === 'over'
    ? (nameOver50 = person
        .filter(({ name, age }) => age > 50)
        .map(({ name }) => name))
    : (nameUnder50 = person
        .filter(({ name, age }) => age < 50)
        .map(({ name }) => name));
}

check('over');
check('under');

console.log(nameOver50);
console.log(nameUnder50);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only logging nameUnder50 yet you are passing 'over' to the function

`nameOver50` is the array you should be logging or both:

```js
const person = [
    { name: 'Jessica', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Ilary', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Frank', age: 70 },
    { name: 'Dan', age: 65 },
    { name: 'Pop', age: 22 },
    { name: 'Maur', age: 68 },
  ];
  
  let nameOver50 = [];
  let nameUnder50 = [];
  
  function check(enter) {
    person.filter(({ name, age }) => {
      if (age > 50 && enter === 'over') {
        nameOver50.push( name );
        // nameOver50.push({ name });
        // You could alternatively just push the name, if you want an array of the names only
      } else if (age < 50 && enter === 'under') {
        nameUnder50.push(name);
      }
    });
    console.log(nameUnder50);
    console.log(nameOver50);
  }
  
  check('over');
  check('under');
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks to you and thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the result of `filter()`, so it should be `forEach()`.

You need to display the appropriate array depending on `enter`.

```js
const person = [
  { name: 'Jessica', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ilary', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 70 },
  { name: 'Dan', age: 65 },
  { name: 'Pop', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Maur', age: 68 },
];

let nameOver50 = [];
let nameUnder50 = [];

function check(enter) {
  person.forEach(({ name, age }) => {
    if (age > 50 && enter === 'over') {
      nameOver50.push({ name });
    } else if (age < 50 && enter === 'under') {
      nameUnder50.push(name);
    }
  });
  if (enter === 'over') {
    console.log(nameOver50);
  } else {
    console.log(nameUnder50);
  }
}

check('over');
```